# new Date() Scheduled Script returning UTC not local time

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

I have a function in my library to return the current date:

```
function currentDate(addDays) {
    if (addDays == null||addDays == undefined) { 
        addDays = 0; 
    }
    var currentdate = new Date();
    var current = nlapiAddDays(currentdate,addDays);
    var day = current.getDate();
    var month = current.getMonth()+1
    var year = current.getFullYear();
    return day+'/'+month+'/'+year;
}
```

All works fine, until I run a scheduled script which utilises this function, at which point the date returned is UTC, not our local time. Is there a simplistic method of conversion within this function *without* the need for external libraries?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a utils function that I've used for years.

```
function getCompanyDate(){
    var currentDateTime = new Date();
    var companyTimeZone = nlapiLoadConfiguration('companyinformation').getFieldText('timezone');
    var timeZoneOffSet = (companyTimeZone.indexOf('(GMT)') == 0) ? 0 : new Number(companyTimeZone.substr(4, 6).replace(/\+|:00/gi, '').replace(/:30/gi, '.5'));
    var UTC = currentDateTime.getTime() + (currentDateTime.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000);
    var companyDateTime = UTC + (timeZoneOffSet * 60 * 60 * 1000);

    return new Date(companyDateTime);
}
```

It uses your company's NetSuite settings and timezone.  This will return the date in the correct timezone assuming your NetSuite settings are correct.

You could then essentially do:

```
function currentDate(addDays) {
if (addDays == null||addDays == undefined) { 
    addDays = 0; 
}
var currentdate = getCompanyDate();
var current = nlapiAddDays(currentdate,addDays);
var day = current.getDate();
var month = current.getMonth()+1
var year = current.getFullYear();
return day+'/'+month+'/'+year;
}
```

Comment: One question Lez... How to get around the permissions if the user does not have company config permissions?

Comment: I am getting this error: `ReferenceError: nlapiLoadConfiguration is not defined at getCompanyDate`

Comment: Disregard above, turned out I was calling the function from the UI area as well, so could not load config from client side. Easily remedied with a couple of context checks.

Comment: For SuiteScript 2.0, i think this needs to be modified. I'm working on something at the moment and will share once I have findings.

Answer (score 2):

Suitescript 2.0 version of @lez-yeoh getCompanyDate

```js
function getCompanyDate(){
    var currentDateTime = new Date();
    var companyTimeZone = config.load({ type: config.Type.COMPANY_INFORMATION }).getText({ fieldId: 'timezone' });
    var timeZoneOffSet = (companyTimeZone.indexOf('(GMT)') == 0) ? 0 : Number(companyTimeZone.substr(4, 6).replace(/\+|:00/gi, '').replace(/:30/gi, '.5'));
    var UTC = currentDateTime.getTime() + (currentDateTime.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000);
    var companyDateTime = UTC + (timeZoneOffSet * 60 * 60 * 1000);

    return new Date(companyDateTime);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I do but you consume usage units since you have to create record.

First I create a hidden custom Date/Time field. Then I use the following code.

```
var record = nlapiCreateRecord(<recordtype>);
record.setDateTimeValue(<fieldid>, nlapiDateToString(new Date(), 'datetimetz', 5);
var userDateTime = record.getFieldValue(<fieldid>);
```

The variable userDateTime should now be in the local time zone.

The nlapiSetDateTimeValue() API function will convert the date/time value to the user's timezone.  Below is its syntax:

nlapiSetDateTimeValue(fieldId, dateTime, timeZone)

1. fieldId = Id of the date/time field.
2. dateTime = Date value to be converted.
3. timeZone = The timezone of the date being passed.  If its a server side script, it is usually in Pacific so we pass the Olson value of 5.

Comment: Would be worth looking at Lez' script, only costs 10api points